# Complex numbers, equation

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Let $f(z) = 3z^2 + 1$

Show that if $\vert z \vert = 1$ and $\vert f(z) \vert = 2$, then $z = \pm i$.

My attempt:
Start with the equation $\vert f(z) \vert = 2$.
So we can re-write $\vert f(z) \vert = \vert 3z^2 + 1 \vert$  as $2 = \vert 3z^2 + 1 \vert$.

But here Im stuck. I know that $i^2=-1$, but can I use that somehow?

Comment: Do you know the triangle inequality?

Comment: If you've worked with the polar form for complex numbers, you are told that $ \ z \ = \ \cos  \theta + i \sin \theta \ \ ,  \ $ since the modulus of $ \ z \ $ is $ \ 1 \ \ . \ $  How would you write $ \ 3z^2 + 1 \ $ in that form, and what would its modulus be?  If that modulus equals $ \ 2 \ \ , \ $ what values will $ \ \theta \ $ have?

Comment: @MarkBennet Yes I do

Comment: @MartinR: It's a mistake, it shouldent be there.

Comment: Following up on the hint of @MarkBennet, do you know when equality holds in the triangle inequality in the complex plane?

Comment: @RobertShore |z + w|≤|z| + |w| for all z,w ∈ C.

Answer (score 2):

Write $z=e^{i\theta}=\cos \theta+i \sin \theta$ and $z^{2}=\cos (2\theta)+i \sin (2\theta)$. $4=|f(z)|^{2}=9 \cos ^{2}(2\theta)+1+6\cos (2 \theta)+9 \sin ^{2}(2\theta)=10+6\cos (2 \theta)$. This gives $\cos (2 \theta)=-1$ ( and hence $\sin (2\theta)=1$). Thus, $z^{2}=-1$ and $z =\pm i$.

Answer (score 1):

$$
 4 = |3z^2+1|^2 = (3z^2+1)(\overline {3z^2}+1) = 9 |z|^4 + 6 \operatorname{Re} (z^2) + 1 = 10 + 6 \operatorname{Re} (z^2)
$$
implies that $\operatorname{Re} (z^2) = -1$.

The only complex number on the unit circle with real part equal to $-1$ is $-1$. So $z^2 = -1$ and therefore $z=i$ or $z=-i$.